# My log4j2.xml changes are not being picked

Tags: java, automation, log4j

I am creating an automation framework using the usual suspects - restassured, testng, selenium, appium, etc..
While I have log4j configured, my log4j2.xml file is being read but not being used.
I followed this article to configure log4j2.xml file - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html.

How do I know if its read? - Console output starts with this line which gives the absolutePath to the .xml file.

> Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[

How I know its not being used? - My log4j2 **pattern** is:

> pattern="%m MDC%X%n"

and the log which is getting printed is like this:

> `16:51:11.886 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "39[\r][\n]"`

I see slf4j in project external libraries, which might be a required dependency for one of the dependencies. I did start off with slf4j, but eventually came back to log4j2.
Its annoying since I am getting a lot of unwanted logs (mainly `org.apache.http`) whenever I need to debug a failed test.

log4j dependency in pom.xml is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What should I do here?

Comment: Properties non supported you should use XML.

Comment: @RomanC sorry, I am using log4j2.xml